# Helm chart failing with Required value

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to create a Helm chart for kafka-connect. For the testing purpose and to find out where I am exactly wrong I am not using the secrets for my access key and secret access key.

My helm chart is failing with the error:

```
helm install helm-kafka-0.1.0.tgz --namespace prod -f helm-kafka/values.yaml
Error: release loping-grizzly failed: Deployment.apps "kafka-connect" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[15].name: Required value
```

Based on issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/46861

I changed my number to be a string. But still, the issue persists.

Can someone point me on how to troubleshoot/solve this?

My template/deployment.yaml

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kafka-connect
          image: {{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}
          env:

           - name: "CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS"
             value: "org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR"

           - name: "CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC"
             value: "connect-offsets"

           - name: "CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH"
             value: "/usr/share/java"

           - name: "CONNECT_PRODUCER_ACKS"
             value: "all"

           - name: "CONNECT_PRODUCER_COMPRESSION_TYPE"
             value: "snappy"

           - nane: "CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC"
             value: "connect-status"
```

Comment: check you yaml syntax , after image , the env list doe not seem to be proper

Comment: I checked that , if you replace the image to test:123 it returned me vaild yaml!

Comment: looks like the typo was the problem. Was there any issue with the image line?

Comment: No, there was no issue with the image line. It was the typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In:

```
- nane: "CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC"
  value: "connect-status"
```

`nane:` should have an "m".

When the error message says `spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[15].name` you can find the first (zero-indexed) container definition, and within that the sixteenth (zero-indexed) environment variable, which has this typo.

Answer (score 3):

There's something wrong with the substitution of:

```
image: {{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}
```

One or both the values don't exist in your `Values.yaml`. Or one or both have extra characters, possibly newlines.

If you look at the [upstream chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/incubator/kafka/values.yaml), you see that it has `image` and `imageTag`, so in your template, you would have to have something like this:

```
image: {{ .Values.image }}:{{ .Values.imageTag }}
```